# How to read the cert from TLS/SSL certificates in function app to make HTTPS call using Java code

Tags: java, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

Scenario:

1. The function app makes the call to the Https endpoint
2. Using HttpClient Java 11
3. Java requires trusted cert to make this call
4. Adding the public cert in the TLS/SSL section of the function app so that the app can read the cert and pass it in the SSLContext to make HTTPS call

Answer (score 0):

In your application code, you can access the public certificates you add to App Service. A certificate uploaded into an app is stored in a deployment unit that is **bound to the app service plan**. So to read your public certificate you first have to **add/upload** it in **TLS/SSL settings** of app service.

Check this [upload a public certificate document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#upload-a-public-certificate) for detailed information on how to add the public certificate.

In Java code, you access the certificate from the "Windows-MY" store using the Subject Common Name field. Following code show how to read a certificate using Java code :

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; 
import java.security.KeyStore; 
import java.security.cert.Certificate; 
import java.security.PublicKey;

... 

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY"); 
ks.load(null, null); 
Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate("<subject-cn>");
```

Check the [Use a TLS/SSL certificate in your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code#load-certificate-in-windows-apps) documentation for more information.